# Textbox VerticalScrollbar doesn't work properly - bug or I'm doing it wrong ? - Windows Store App

Tags: c#, .net, windows-8, windows-store-apps

I have a TextBox in a Windows Store App and i wanted to enable the vertical scrollbar.

```
<TextBox Name="myTextBox" 
     ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
</TextBox>
```

The problem is the scrollbar only works with the mouse wheel, it doesn't move if i click on the scrollbar and move it up or down.

Also the up arrow of the scrollbar doesn't work, but the down arrow works.

Is this a bug from Visual Studio or am I missing something?

Here is the complete code:

```
            <TextBox x:Name="descriptionTextBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="132,110,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="345" Width="295" FontSize="20" BorderThickness="0" FontFamily="Segoe Print" 
                 ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" AcceptsReturn="True">
            <TextBox.Background>
                <ImageBrush/>
            </TextBox.Background>
        </TextBox>
```

The textBox is inside a Grid.

Comment: Do you not have TextWrapping="Wrap" set?  With that set, it's working fine for me.  Without it set though, I'd expect you to be seeing odder behavior.  What's the enclosing XAML container?

Comment: Yes it does have TextWrapping. It is inside a Grid. I've updated the post with the complete code. This behavior is very strange.

Comment: I've tried to use the textbox on an empty project and it works fine. On my project I've deleted the textBox and added a new one. Seems to work fine until I stretch it to the right so it is aligned with the textbox above it. Very strange.

Comment: I've managed to find my error. It was overlapping grids. Thanks for the tip and leading me to the problem !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was with overlapping grids.

Comment: What do you mean by overlapping grids. I am getting the same problem.

Comment: One UI item was on top of the other UI item. So only the one from the top worked.